# Android Webview - Uncaught ReferenceError in local javascript execution

Tags: javascript, android-activity, android-webview

Hello everyone and thanks for your help!

I want to build a Android Webview App, it uses HTML + CSS + javascript with no library except the highcharts one. It works perfectly well cross-browser when I try it with the files on the server.

I want to have as many files as possible running locally client-side: the HTML, CSS, all assets (images) and javascript codes are in the app, leaving only the php files on the server (login, signin, etc.).

Unfortunately, when I try my app on Android, I get errors on my javascript function defeinitions, for instance:
    12-27 10:04:42.075 17798-17798/com.wifcompanion.wifcompanion D/WiFCompanionConsole: Uncaught ReferenceError: BodyReset is not defined -- From line 22 of file:///android_asset/wifmobile.html

My first intuition was that the .js files were not loaded properly. So I put all the js code directly under the  tag in wifmobile.html. To no avail.

What's more, it seems some functions are found (for instance NewSignIn() when I click on the front-page login button), while others are not (for instance PopupSave(), which is a function called in NewSignIn()).

The closest question I could find on stackoverflow is here, but does not have any answer:
[JavaScript not working with android WebView, Uncaught ReferenceError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150464/javascript-not-working-with-android-webview-uncaught-referenceerror)

## MainActivity:

```
package com.wifcompanion.wifcompanion;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView m_webview = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create WebView
    m_webview = new WebView(this);

    // Add WebView to Activity
    m_webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewWIF);
    m_webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    m_webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/wifmobile.html");

    //Logcat and console
    m_webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
            Log.d("WiFCompanionConsole", cm.message() + " -- From line "
                    + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
                    + cm.sourceId() );
            return true;
        }
    });


    // Reload the old WebView content
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        m_webview.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
    // Create the WebView
    else {
        m_webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            fixNewAndroid(m_webview);
        }
    }
}

// Save the state of the web view when the screen is rotated.
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    m_webview.saveState(outState);
}

@TargetApi(16)
protected void fixNewAndroid(WebView webView) {
    try {
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
}
```

}

## wifmobile.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Title -->
<title>World in Flames Companion</title>

<!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
<!-- icon -->
<link rel="icon" href="img/icon/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icon/wiflogo48.png" />
<!-- jQuery library -->
<!--<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>-->
<!-- Highharts -->
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<!-- WIF scripts -->
<script src="solifnav.js"></script>
<script src="solif.js"></script>
<script src="soliffal.js"></script>
<script src="solifsetup.js"></script>
<script src="solifpartisans.js"></script> 
<script src="solifflow.js"></script>
<script src="solifcards.js"></script>
<script src="solifdiplo.js"></script>
<script src="solifbenefits.js"></script>
<script src="solifvichy.js"></script>
<script src="solifinternal.js"></script>
<script src="solifgamemanagement.js"></script>
<script src="solifbuild.js"></script>
<script src="solifhelper.js"></script>
<script src="solifdatabase.js"></script>
<script src="solifintel.js"></script>
<script src="solifstats.js"></script>
<script src="solifcivilwar.js"></script>
<script src="solifvp.js"></script>
<!-- Scenario specifics -->
<script src="solifscenario4.js"></script>
<!-- Stylehseet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="wifmobile.css">
<!-- Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton|Russo+One|Fanwood+Text|UnifrakturCook:700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body onclick="BodyReset(event);" onkeydown="BodyKeydown(event);">
<!-- Login / registration / forgotpassword page-->                                      
<div id="signin">
<div class="banner"><img src="img/icon/wiflogo.png" style="max-width:75%;" /></div>
<div id="login">
<input type="text" name="login-username" id="login-username" placeholder="User name" autocomplete="username">
<input type="password" name="login-password" id="login-password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="current-password">
<a onclick="NewSignIn();" id="NewSignInButton">Login</a>
<a onclick="GotoRegister();" class="things">&gt;&gt; Register</a>
<a onclick="GotoForgot();" class="things">&gt;&gt; Forgot your password?</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely an error in the **javascript** code. Namely, as I'm using an old device (tablet must be from early 2010's), the webview is not compliant with **Javascript ECMAScript 6**. Instead, you should make sure your code is **Javascript ECMAScript 5** compliant.

This includes (those are the main errors I found in my code):

1) Don't use default parameters declaration in functions. Instead of:

```
    function myFunction(myParam='hello'){
        ...
    }
```

Use:

```
    function myFunction(myParam){
        myParam=myParam || 'hello';
        ...
    }
```

2) Your functions should not hold the same "name" (case-sensitive) as an id in your html. For instance don't do this:

```
    <a id="MyLink" onclick="MyLink();">My link</a>
```

But do this:

```
    <a id="MyLink" onclick="myLink();">My link</a>
```

3) If like me, you're not a damn pro, prepare to test every single line of your code, because even some things as simple as console.clear() weren't compliant.

I will edit this post as I find some more obvious errors.